# Arabic/Farsi/ UTF8 in Text mining in R

Tags: r

So I want to make a word cloud in RStudio in Windows 8.1 So this my code.
And I read here that with this piece of code:

```
tm_map(yourCorpus, function(x) iconv(enc2utf8(x), sub = "byte"))
```

I cloud solve the UTF8 Problem in RStudio.

```
library(twitteR)
library(tm)
library(wordcloud)
library(RColorBrewer)

load("twitteR_credentials")
registerTwitterOAuth(twitCred)

mach_tweets = searchTwitter("ایرانسل", n=500 , cainfo="cacert.pem")

mach_text = sapply(mach_tweets, function(x) x$getText())

mach_corpus = Corpus(VectorSource(mach_text))

tdm = TermDocumentMatrix(mach_corpus,
                         control = list(removePunctuation = TRUE,
                         stopwords = c("", ""),
                         removeNumbers = TRUE, tolower = TRUE),
                         iconv(enc2utf8(x), sub = "byte"))

m = as.matrix(tdm)
word_freqs = sort(rowSums(m), decreasing=TRUE)
dm = data.frame(word=names(word_freqs), freq=word_freqs)

wordcloud(dm$word, dm$freq, random.order=FALSE, colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))

png("MachineLearningCloud.png", width=12, height=8, units="in", res=300)
     wordcloud(dm$word, dm$freq, random.order=FALSE, colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))
dev.off()
```

but when I tried it shows gibbrish.

Comment: Are the tweets in Arabic/Farsi or in English?  Your stopwords argument calls for English.  And, presumably you mean the wordcloud was gibberish, not the plotting of it.

Comment: @lawyeR I checked it, when I removed it. Still it gives me gibberish.

Comment: Can you finally solve this problem? I'm in a similar situation!